# How to install an app I write twice?

Tags: android, eclipse

I need to have both earlier and later versions of App I write in Eclipse.
What do I need to change (activity name?) to upload new version of the app to my phone without overwriting the old one? Any fast way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package name in the manifest identifies the application (see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)). So you also need to change the package name.

Answer (score 0):

Change the app name in your manifest file.

Comment: On emulator it doesn't work, it overwrites old app. Will work on actual phone?